# Travis CI QT not building

Tags: c++, qt, travis-ci

So I wanted to use travis for [this](https://github.com/DJLectr0/BetaLauncher) project today. Sadly it failed with this error:

```
$ make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o downloadmanager.o downloadmanager.cpp
In file included from downloadmanager.h:11:0,
                 from downloadmanager.cpp:1:
mainwindow.h:4:23: fatal error: QMainWindow: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [downloadmanager.o] Error 1
The command "make" exited with 2.
```

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/DJLectr0/BetaLauncher/builds/45380325) is the full log.

Note I first had problems with it not recognizing the Network module file (e.g. QNetworkAccessManager). I fixed this by executing QMake with "QT += network". Now it cannot find the GUI files (e.g. QMessageBox) but adding "QT += network gui" did not do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `widgets` to get classes such as `QMessageBox` and `QMainWindow`:

```
QT += widgets network gui
```

For future reference, please consult the Qt 5 documentation.  The page for each class indicates what must be added to your `qmake` for that class (right at the top of the page).  See, for example, the page for [`QMessageBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html).